# Declare Data Table on handlebars template

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, handlebars.js

i have recently started using handlerbar.js in my projects and it seems quite interesting.So far so good, but im struggling in creating dynamic data grids using a template.

i have following json

```
gridrow: [
    { col1: 'a', col2: 'b', col3: 'c' }, 
    { col1: 'd', col2: 'e', col3: 'f' }, 
    { col1: 'g', col2: 'h', col3: 'i' }
]
```

when I create template

```
<tbody>
<table id="dt_scroll">
{{#each gridrow}}
    <tr>
        <td>{{col1}}</td>
        <td>{{col2}}</td>
        <td>{{col3}}</td>
    </tr>
{{/each}}
</table>
</tbody>
```

when I declare datatable for table dt_scroll show error

```
$invoice_preview.html(theCompiledHtml);
$invoice_form.html('');
$window.resize();
$dt_scroll = $('#dt_scroll');
console.log($dt_scroll.length);
if ($dt_scroll.length) {
    $('#dt_scroll').DataTable({
        "scrollY": "200px",
        "scrollCollapse": false,
        "paging": false
    });
}
```

[image: image error]

Comment: Where is your `DataTable` function. Are you sure is it declarated?

Comment: yes I'm sure it's declare the console log return value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume the problem is that the browser tries to parse the `<table/>`. When you try that, it will fail. `{{#each gridrow}}` is not allowed as a first child of a table.

To fix this, simply put your template in a script tag. I also fixed here your HTML because it wasn't valid for the DataTable plugin

```
<div id="invoice_preview"></div>

<script type="x-template" id="dt_scroll">
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>1.</th>
        <th>2.</th>
        <th>3.</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      {{#each gridrow}}
      <tr>
        <td>{{col1}}</td>
        <td>{{col2}}</td>
        <td>{{col3}}</td>
      </tr>
      {{/each}}
    </tbody>
  </table>
</script>
```

Now the JavaScript code has to look similar to something like this.

```
var context = {title: "My New Post", gridrow: [
    { col1: 'a', col2: 'b', col3: 'c' }, 
    { col1: 'd', col2: 'e', col3: 'f' }, 
    { col1: 'g', col2: 'h', col3: 'i' }
]}

// compile the template
var html = Handlebars.compile($('#dt_scroll').html())(context)

// setting the compiled html
var $invoice_preview = $('#invoice_preview')
$invoice_preview.html(html)

// start the plugin
$invoice_preview.find(">:first-child").DataTable({
  "scrollY": "200px",
  "scrollCollapse": false,
  "paging": false
})
```